# Return line after looking up for a value in a range of values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need help to get the following result. Explanation below image:

[image: Excel Spredsheet]

The only editable cell is A2.

When I insert a value in A2, C2 prints the corresponding line from the table A5:C11.

E.g., if I put any number between A7 and B7 (33-40), it should print line 7 in C2. For instance, if I put 35, it returs `33 40  R$ 4.069,80`.

If I change the value in A2 to, let's say, 55, cell C2 returns `51  60  R$ 6.300,00` (because 55 is in the 51-60 range).

I've tried without success using VLOOKUP and XLOOKUP. I dunno what to do from now on.

Comment: The intellisense of your formula while typing XLOOKUP should have given the idea: `XLOOKUP(A2,A6:A11,A6:C11,"",-1)` which searches the closest lower value.

Comment: @Notus_Panda how can I flag your answer as correct? Because it solved it.

Comment: Posted an answer down below, glad it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you wanted a separate answer:

When typing a formula, there are optional parameters which can sometimes be helpful.
In this case, the Match mode:

[image]

I'd prefer the slightly adjusted formula so you get a warning when the target number doesn't fall between any range

> =IF(OR(A2<A6,B11<A2),"OUT OF BOUNDS",XLOOKUP(A2,A6:A11,A6:C11,"",-1))

If the ranges aren't sorted like you have them now, you can opt for the min/max bounds like user11222393 has them.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If all data is sorted like in example, this would work:

```
=if(and(A2<=max(A6:B11),A2>=min(A6:B11)),index(A6:C11,match(A2,A6:A11,1)),"Not found")
```

or

```
=if(and(A2<=max(A6:B11),A2>=min(A6:B11)),xlookup(A2,A6:A11,A6:C11,,-1),"Not found")
```

or

```
=if(A2<=max(A6:B11),xlookup(A2,A6:A11,A6:C11,"Not found",-1),"Not found")
```

[image]

For `A2` values bigger or less than found in `A6:B11` "Not found" is shown.

Answer (score 0):

`VLOOKUP` formula should work.  Try it this way:

> =VLOOKUP(A2,A6:C11,3,TRUE)

Use `TRUE` in the last argument of the `VLOOKUP` formula (`is_sorted`) to find the approximate value.  This should return the correct result as long as your lookup range is sorted in order of least to greatest (which it currently is in your example).

In other words, the `VLOOKUP` will look for an approximate match and return "Yes" in the example below for all numbers in cell A2 from 51-60.  It will return "Maybe" if your number in A2 is 61-70.  Using `FALSE` in the last argument will return an exact match only.

Use this formula in C2 and D2 to show the correct search results.  Change the index number as necessary.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The XLOOKUP formula as used by Notus_Panda in the comment to your question is also an option.

Comment: Question is to return all 3 columns as a result, so using VLOOKUP it should be =arrayformula(vlookup(A2,A6:C11,{1,2,3})) also search value >77 will return incorrect result

Comment: That is just an example of the formula to put in cell E2,  The formula can be adjusted easily to populate the correct values in C2 and D2.  You are correct, your formula will populate all three cells with the correct value.

Comment: In regard to a number >77 returning the incorrect result, I made the assumption that the OP's values being searched for for would fall within ranges specified by OP.  If that is the case, the above formula(s) would be sufficient.  If not, this answer does indeed fail to address that possibility.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but sadly it needs to work with numbers out of the ranges (smaller than the smallest = shows the smaller number. Larger than the largest = show the larger)